# My animator is creating Simultaneous animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two characters (enemy) having the same Animator Controller and they play animations Simultaneously. The timing for their animations is exactly the same. Is there a way I can make variations among them so that they look a bit more natural.

Comment: You would need two separate `AnimatorControllers` for this

Comment: @derHugo I am making an enemy spawner that spawns an Enemy Prefab. Is there a way I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that even if you access the correct instance of the `Animator` they all still share the same `AnimatorController` asset.

=> You need a separate individual `AnimatorControllers` for each instance of the animator.

You can create them for each instance on runtime e.g. using

```c#
[RequrieComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class AnimatorControllerCloner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator _animator;

    private void Start()
    {
        if(!_animator) _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        var runtimeController = _animator.runtimeAnimatorController;
        var newController = Instantiate(runtimeController);
        _animator.runtimeAnimatorController = newController;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me what exactly animator.runtimeAnimatorController does because there is no proper documentation on it.

Comment: [`RuntimeAnimatorController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeAnimatorController.html) -> `The runtime representation of the AnimatorController. Use this representation to change the Animator Controller during runtime.` Thing is an `AnimatorController` is a scriptable object that only exists in the UnityEditor. On runtime (therefore the name) you use a reduced class that does not have any of the UnityEditor stuff like a drawer etc. Basically the `AnimatorController` inherits and extends the `RuntimeAnimatorController` with additional tools only needed within Unity itself.