# How do I Code in Unity an onTriggerEnter into a Prefab to only trigger single Prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

So here is my Problem

```
public class TunnelTrg : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider ohter)
    {
        anim = Animator.FindObjectOfType<Animator>();
        anim.Play("R_WallTunnel");
    }
}
```

After the OnTriggerEnter got triggered each existing Prefab of this starts the Animation, how do i fix it to only trigger the single Prefab by entering?

The OnTriggerEnter is Cube that starts to close a Door after triggering it, but now all doors of the existing prefabs are getting closed.

Comment: First of all you would need to **not use `FindObjetcOfType`** but rather get a reference to the correct instance using `GetComponent` on the according `GameObject`. Then still the main issue here is that even if you would access the correct instance of the animator they still all share the same `AnimatorController` asset! Please see the duplicate link for a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

If all your animators start running, you probably have them set up in a wrong way. Share some info/screenshots about your prefabs.

But you are also searching the Animators globally, you don't need to. It's faster and better to get the component directly from the object that OnTriggerEnter runs on.

```
public class TunnelTrg : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    private void Start()
    {
        anim = getComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        anim.Play("R_WallTunnel");
    }
}
```

edit: uh, if the door is the "other" object, use this code:

```
public class TunnelTrg : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Animator anim = other.getComponent<Animator>();
        if(anim != null)
           anim.Play("R_WallTunnel");
    }
}
```

Comment: This alone will not fix the problem. See the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62511106/my-animator-is-creating-simultaneous-animation/62511228#62511228). Even if you access the correct instance of the animator they still all share the same `AnimatorController` asset.

Comment: Sadly it doesnt work. So there is an static Cube without Mesh and trigger on, if the player moves into that cube a Door thats ahead should start to open. But the entire thing (Cube and door) are in a Prefab, so the problem is when ever the player Triggers the Cube all Prefabs of it open their own doors. (Im new in Unity so idk what actully goes into the (Collider "ohter"))